# One to Many with Entity Framework not updating the foreign key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I need some help, I have been searching everywhere for ages to why this keeps happening.  I basically have 2 tables, Company and Address.  A company can have multiple addresses.  My classes and tables look like the following

TABLES:

```
create table Company (
    companyid int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY not null,
    name varchar(100),
    agencyref varchar(20),
    website varchar(100),
    phoneno varchar(20),
    faxno varchar(20),
    modified datetime DEFAULT (GETDATE())   
);

create table Address (
      addressid int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY not null,
      companyid int null, //Does the same if set to not null
        addressLine1 varchar(100),
        addressLine2 varchar(100),
        city varchar(50),
        county varchar(100),
        postcode varchar(10),
        modified datetime DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
        foreign key ( companyid ) references Company (companyid)
);
```

CLASSSES

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int companyid { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Company Name:")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Client Reference:")]
    public string agencyref { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Website Address:")]
    public string website { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Phone No:")]
    public string phoneno { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Fax No:")]
    public string faxno { get; set; }

    private DateTime _modified = DateTime.Now;
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime modified
    {
        get { return _modified; }
        set { _modified = value; }
    }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int addressid { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Address Line 1:")]
    public string addressline1 { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Address Line 2:")]
    public string addressline2 { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("City:")]
    public string city { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("County:")]
    public string county { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Postcode:")]
    public string postcode { get; set; }

    private DateTime _modified = DateTime.Now;

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime modified
    {
        get { return _modified; }
        set { _modified = value; }
    }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

My MODEL BUILDER

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasMany(c => c.Address).WithOptional(p => p.Company).Map(c => c.MapKey("companyid"));
```

I have been using Code First and the database is already there.  the results I get from the database is:

COMPANY TABLE:

```
companyid   name    agencyref   website phoneno faxno   modified
4   erg NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2012-12-20 13:20:56.430
```

ADDRESS TABLE:

```
addressid   companyid   addressLine1    addressLine2    city    county  postcode    modified
2   NULL    hkjh    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2012-12-20 13:50:37.977
```

As you can see I expect the companyid in Address Table to be populated with 4, but for some reason this is not doing that.

Wonder if anyone can help me solve this frustrating problem.  I thought it was simple to use a view attached to a view model, that returned two classes populated with data, then insert this into the database:

My clientModel class is nice and simple:

```
public class ClientModel
{
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

MY VIEW on the controller is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(ClientModel client)
    {
       // CompanyAddress ca = new CompanyAddress();
        Domain.Data.EFDbContext context = new Domain.Data.EFDbContext();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Companies.Add(client.Company);
            context.Addresses.Add(client.Address);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(client);
        }
    }
```

This is so my Edit page contains

```
@model TimesheetMVC.WebUI.Models.ClientModel
```

(enclosed within a FormMethod.Post)

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Company Details</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company.name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Company.name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company.name)
    </div>        
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company.agencyref)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Company.agencyref)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company.agencyref)
    </div>

</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Address Details</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address.addressline1)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.addressline1)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address.addressline1)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address.addressline2)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.addressline2)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address.addressline2)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address.city)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.city)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address.city)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address.county)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.county)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address.county)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address.postcode)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.postcode)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address.postcode)
    </div>
```

Any help please......

Comment: Is there a way to configure the framework to produce the SQL output? Also, I think you should specify a cascade behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be saving your data incorrectly. Have you tried adding your address data to your company model, then saving just the company:

```
Domain.Data.EFDbContext context = new Domain.Data.EFDbContext();
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    client.Company.Address.Add(client.Address);
    context.Companies.Add(client.Company);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
else
{
    return View(client);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Brilliant, I never thought of doing that, been playing around with so many other options.  I have also had to add a public constructor to the Company class for some reason, otherwise I kept getting null exception.  Public Company() { Address = new HashSet<Address>() }; not sure why it would not work without it, unless I am missing something else.

Comment: No, you're not missing anything. That's precisely what you should be doing. I forgot to mention that in my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, will change all my classes to reflect this, one thing I also did forget to ask, is how do I retrieve the data now that I have populated the database?  Thanks

Comment: If you need to get a company with the addresses, you can do this: context.Companies.Include("Addresses").Single(co => co.companyid == id). There may be a better way to do it in this scenario, but this is the only way I know how to do it. If all you need is the company, you can do this: context.Companies.Find(id).

Comment: Thank you very much this worked a treat.  All the example shows the single table mapping, do you have any sites to look into this multi mapping more.

Comment: Another question, if I add public virtual IColleciton<Contact> CompanyContact {get; set} to my Company class, even though I have not implemented this anywhere it keeps asking for navigation or errors saying Invalid column name Contact_id even though I do not call this in the search you gave me or try to display.  This will cause me problems down the line as some my pages reference multiple tables and some don't, so not sure how to tell it to exclude what it does not need.  Thats if you can.

Comment: The only sites I can think of off the top of my head are asp.net and pluralsight.com. The first MVC 3 app I developed was from a tutorial on asp.net. And I've picked up a lot on EF from videos on pluralsight.com, but that's a subscription-based site. The rest has been through Google and Stackoverflow.

Comment: With regard to your EF error. Are you using Entity Framework Code First? If so, that may be the problem. When you change your entity classes you need to drop the database and let the framework re-create it. See the "When Classes Change" section from [this video](http://pluralsight.com/training/players/PSODPlayer?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-data-i&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro) on asp.net for a better explanation.

Comment: Hi, I am using code first as I was following examples in the book Pro Asp.net framework.  But that was for simple one table sites, when you start getting more complex seems less information there.  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: No problem. By the way, I didn't mean that it was a problem that you were using Entity Framework Code First. I think it's great and I still use it for developing new applications. The problem I was referring to was that when you change an entity class by adding another property or taking one out, Entity Framework needs to re-create your database to include/exclude the properties. But it won't do it unless you delete the database. Check the link to the video out, it provides a good explanation.

Comment: Dont worry didnt take it that way, I knew what you meant.  Thank you for the video, I watched it and I did that and I have applied the needed changes to the program so it recreates on every class change.  I may also join that site as there seems to be loads of information that could be handy and also get the Entity Framework book by Julia as that seems very informative.  Thanks again for all your assistance.